# How to customize Root tags in Talend tFileOutputXML

Tags: xml, tags, talend

I have created Talend procedure that outputs xml file with tFileOutputXML. It works fine, but problem is that my Root tags in footer node tag has to be diffrent as is header node tag.

In Advanced settings I have add root as:

[image]

The code is generated by it self and it looks like this:

```
String[] footers_tFileOutputXML_1 = new String[2];

headers_tFileOutputXML_1[1] = "<"
                    + "rss xmlns:g='http://base.google.com/ns/1.0' version='2.0'"
                    + ">";

footers_tFileOutputXML_1[0] = "</"
                    + "rss xmlns:g='http://base.google.com/ns/1.0' version='2.0'"
                    + ">";
```

But I need that footers_tFileOutputXML_1[0] is look like this:

```
footers_tFileOutputXML_1[0] = "</"
                    + "rss"
                    + ">";
```

I tried to edit with java editor and save, but it generate code again. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `tAdvancedFileOuputXML` component to be able to specify a namespace.

Click on `Configure XML Tree` on the component tab.

[image]

1. Rename the root tag as "rss"
2. Right click to name the attribute "version" and set a static value
3. Right click to set a namespace.

Result :

[image]